# Keras layer feature labels

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras-layer

Is keras model layer ferature labels are same to the orginal labels

```
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(380,name = 'dense_1'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(classes_num ))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))


model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                        metrics=['accuracy',mean_pred,recall,precision,fmeasure,                               matthews_correlation,kullback_leibler_divergence,
                                 binary_crossentropy])
model.summary()
print('model complied!!')

print('starting training....')

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=64,validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

extract =Model(model.input,[model.get_layer("dense_1").output,model.output])
test_feature,test_labels= extract.predict(X_test)
```

Is the test_labels and y_test are same or not.If i want to use the layer features what labels i should use

Answer (score 0):

test_label is a decimals that shows probability of membership in each class and it is not same as y_test. if you get index of maximum value in output of softmax layer it shows the class that your network determine according to inputs.